# Use spherical coordinates to calculate the triple integral over a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use spherical coordinates to calculate the triple integral of
$$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ over the region $ x^2+y^2+z^2≤6z $.
$$\iiint \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dV=?$$
I tried computing this integral for the answer, but I was incorrect $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{6\cos(\phi)} p^3\sin(\phi) \ dp\,d\phi\,d\theta$$
I am confused what the bounds end up being for p since $p^2≤6p\cos(\phi)$, I came to what I have by dividing the p on both sides, but I am not sure if there should be a lower bound.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This poster has made a reasonable effort to solve a problem and got stuck. It's also formatted correctly in latex, which is also impressive for a completely new poster. What is the reason for the downvoting and close vote?

Comment: Ahhh sorry.... It came into my mind in morning you made the typical mistake. Bizmut angle $\phi$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$... But you did the hardest part found $6\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have done this already, but it may be a useful step to draw a graph of $x^2+y^2+z^2=6z$. Leaving out the $y$ coordinate, plot $x^2+z^2=6z$ and you'll see it's a circle of radius 3 with the origin at $(0,0,3)$. So the limits of integration for the $\rho$ (`\rho`) integral which you arrived at,

> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{6\cos\phi} \rho^3\sin\phi \ d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$$

are correct. However, you do not need to integrate $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$, but from $0$ to $\pi/2$, since the entire function is above the $xy$ plane. If $z$ is negative then the requirement $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 6z$ does not permit any values. So the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{6\cos\phi} \rho^3\sin\phi \ d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$$
It's clearly symmetric with respect to rotation about the $z$ axis, so the $\theta$ integral merely results in a factor of $2\pi$, and the $\rho$ integral is obviously $\rho^4/4$, so we end up with
$$
{2\pi 6^4\over4}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4\phi\sin\phi \,d\phi
$$
The integrand integrates to $-\cos^5\phi/5$ and inserting the upper and lower values $0$ and $\pi/2$ gives us just $1/5$, so the final answer should be $2\pi 6^4/(4\times5)=648\pi/5$.